# Can I tell perl to emit an alarm/signal when runtime exceeds a certain time limit without exiting?

Tags: perl, timeout, runtime

I'm trying to set an alarm type call that lets me know if my program runs for longer than 10 minutes I want the program to keep running after it sends the alarm or signal. I thought I could do the following code but the program stops when the run time hits ten minutes.

```
eval{
     local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n"; };
     alarm (600);
     --code---
     alarm 0;
};
if($@){
     print "\Its been ten minutes\n";
}
```

I want the application to notify me but to continue running.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SIG_ALARM for this purpose.  If the process is in a system call (e.g.: reading from a file or socket) at the time the the signal arrives, then that system call will fail and return EINTR.  Your code would need to catch this in every place it might occur and retry - very hard to get right.

Comment: @GrantMcLean If you wouldn't recommend using SIG_ALARM, then what would you recommend? I would expect an alternative with your type of response?

Comment: Well, it depends :-) If your code was based around an event framework (Event.pm, POE, etc) then it would be easy to have the framework deliver a message after a timeout.  In the absence of an event framework, then you're really left with having your code check the elapsed time periodically (e.g. on each loop iteration, or each call to a particular function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't die on alarm and you'll be fine,

```
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { print "Its been ten minutes\n"; };
```

Comment: Your original answer with `warn` worked, but not the `print`. If you do what you suggested, it dies like `die`.

Comment: With the warn statement, can I add things like sending me an email when this happens?

Comment: @Question_Guy check output buffering. `warn` goes to STDERR so I guess you could pipe it to mail.